# How do I get the occurences and doc_count of every term of an ES Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an ES Index of the form

```
{
  "adminfile" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "text" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the field 'title' being the title of the string found in the field 'text'. The titles do not contain any spaces, while the texts are normal texts (sentences with spaces and dots etc).

I want to get all the terms in the index and their doc_count and/or frequency. I found this query in the ES doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

```
GET /adminfile/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "aggs" : {
        "text" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "text.keyword",
                "order" : { "_count" : "asc" },
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns all the sources but the aggregation buckets are empty. If I change "text.keyword" to "title.keyword" in that command, it does work and return all the titles as keys.

Why does it not work on the text fields?

Is there a better command to use? I know that this:

```
GET /adminfile/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {"text" : "WordToSearch"}
    },
    "_source":false,
    "aggregations": {
        "keywords" : {
            "significant_text" : {
                "field" : "text",
                "filter_duplicate_text": true,
                "size": 100
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "text": {}
        }
    }
}
```

works to get all occurences of wordToSearch in every document of the index, with the counts and frequency. Is there a way to ask this command to match every word of every doc?

EDIT: I have also tried changing the name of the text field to "contenu" in case ES didn't like have a field of name 'text' and of type 'text'. No effect.

Another option could be using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html but it _termvectors only works for one specific ID (or _mtermvectors for mutliple specific ID, not all the documents in any case)

EDIT2: I realised that the ignore_above could be a problem. I tried cutting all my texts to 200 chars as a test. The query now runs, except that it returns the entire text as a key instead of cutting it into words.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `keyword` version of the field, the content is kept as a single, large token. You're right in assuming that `ignore_above` is the source of your problem, since these tokens apparently will be longer than 256 characters in your data set.

If you instead aggregate across the tokenized field (the normal text field), instead of the `keyword` version, you'll get counts for each word (i.e. each token) as processed by the field.

Comment: Good to know for keyword. Thanks!

I read that this is only possible using fielddata. It seems like this is bad memory-wise. How bad is it?